# Strange IIS behaviour where server responses are being cached

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6

We've a website running since 5 years ago with no problems. A few days ago, users called support, telling they were not able to log into the website. We restarted our servers and all started working properly.

Today we have a product description that was edited (and is correct in our database) but the website won't display the updated value, it keeps displaying the old one.

All these values are retrieved via AJAX and POST method. I was able to see in my chrome Network tab how the server was sending the old response (outdated product description).

I restarted the SQL server, restarted the IIS (from the play button in IIS manager). No luck.

After that I restarted a service called "IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)" and after that, magically, all started working properly.

The only important change we did (afaik) to our server after all these years, which was done 1 month ago, was to enable the compression module for dynamic content.

Now, another user is telling us about another value not being updated after it was edited.

What's going on and why after we restart that process all starts working?

Comment: IIS has its documentation site. It should be your first step to check if the compression results are cached (which might be the cause).

Comment: I've already read all the documentation that was available. The documentation says  POST requests aren't cached. But, strangely, we are not seeing that happening.

Comment: you can run netsh http show cachestate and see anything in the kernel mode cache. Apart form that you need to use Failed Request Event Buffering (FREB) which can give you details about caching for each request. See here on how to enable FREB http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85

Comment: Do you have output caching enabled ? IIS provides kernel mode caching which resides in Http.sys and user caching which resides inside worker process.  Here is more detail https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching